# Implement Google Mercator (Spherical Mercator)

Tags: java, projection, openstreetmap, map-projections, mercator

I would like to use the *Spherical Mercator* algorithm in my application to project lat/lon points to a 2D plane.
The Spherical Mercator is also known as *Google Mercator*, *EPSG-900913* or *EPSG-3785*.

There are several pages how to use this in JavaScript via the OpenLayers library, but I don't use JavaScript.

The [documentation in OpenLayers](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html) didn't help me at all so I would like to ask for help how to implement the Google Mercator in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Libraries to convert form WGS84 (lon/lat) to Mercator:
for Java use eg. geotools or proj4j

if you whant to implement that by yourself:
the article at  Wikipedia is quite useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection

Comment: Thank your for your hint, but this article only covers the standard Mercator projection, not the Spherical Mercator. GeoTools and Proj4j only convert to Mercator.